# Gulp caches generated files

Tags: gulp

I am pretty new at Gulp (v.4.0.2), so I can't understand is there any kind of cache mechanism inside it (at least I can't find such a piece of information on Google). After running my "gulp" command styles.css file being created, but if I do changes in SASS file and the try to run the same command again I won't get a new generated file. I tried to delete styles.css file and run the command again - the file was generated, but with the old content. I can even see that the modification date of the generated file is being left from the old file.

My gulpfile.js:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
const del = require('del');

gulp.task('styles', () => {
    return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
});

gulp.task('clean', () => {
    return del([
        'app/css/styles.css',
    ]);
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(['clean', 'styles']));
```

Comment: Try changing `gulp.task('default', gulp.series(['clean', 'styles']));` to `gulp.task('default', gulp.series('clean', 'styles'));` i.e., without the brackets and see if ithelps.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. I tried to change back to the v.3 and it works fine. Something is wrong with my configuration or the package itself.

Comment: I'm having the same problem out of the blue. Did you downgrade to s specific v3 of gulp? Did you find anything else that could have caused the issue?

Comment: Yes, still using Gulp v.3.9.1. I didn't bother myself too much to update to v.4 after that.